# Why is it possible to reassign a variable holding a reference to a constant?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is it possible to reassign a variable holding a reference to a constant?

```js
const a = {}

var b = a

console.log(a, b)

b = { a: 1 }

console.log(a, b)
```

It's not like I'd have expected this to not be possible (I assume the 'declaration type' (what would be the correct term here?) of a variable (`const`, `let`, `var`) is not passed when assigning, but only defined when declaring).

Does anyone have explicit reference as of how this works in detail?

Comment: The stored reference itself is a value, and `b` is not declared as a constant, that way it's possible to change the value of `b`.

Comment: `b` is not a constant, hence you can change it. I don't see what the issue is here. It not unlike what happens if you do `x = "a"` and then `x = "b"`  - the string you assign is immutable, but that doesn't matter for the reassignment.

Comment: @vlaz Disagreed, because `String`s are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: Nothing in JS is passed by reference, everything is passed by value. The passed (copy of the) reference itself is a value. A correct name for this is "passed by sharing".

Comment: Uh, so are objects. And, again - what is the question - "why am I able to reassign a variable that is not a constant"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume the type of a variable (`const`, `let`, `var`) is not passed when assigning, but only defined when declaring.

True. `a` is declared as `const`, `b` is declared as `var`. They're two different variables, and nothing changes about this when assigning. You can assign a new value to `b` (which you do twice) but you couldn't assign a new value to `a` after the initialisation. That you use the *value of* `a` in the assignment to `b` doesn't matter at all, and it doesn't matter what this value is (a primitive, a mutable object or an immutable object) either.

Comment: I've read this answer multiple times and I couldn't understand that why we need to explain it? Constant value cannot be changed in all programming language. What's new in js?

Comment: @TânNguyễn Maybe OP doesn't know constant values in any programming language? Notice also that in some programming languages that work with references, you can't assign a reference to const memory to a variable with a non-const-reference type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do understand. Do you have any explicit reference of this, though?

Comment: @connexo There are no memory semantics for what you describe in the language, you won't find anyone else talking about this :-) For what `const` does, that's [how it was marketed](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#sec_const-immutability) [from the beginning](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/). You can of course also find it described in the spec, but I can't recommend to read that.